# Show/hide layers (not sublayers) via selector in legend - carto.js v4

Tags: leaflet, layers, legend, carto.js

I am trying to build a layer selector using carts.js.v4, similar to the one provided in Carto Builder.

Examples of layer selectors that I have found utilize sublayers and my maps are using separate layers since each is built using a different database.

The complete code is below and the map is viewable at

http://pstrust.org/carto/ca-pipelines-newdata.htm

```
//GAS DISTRIBUTION
 const gasDistributionDataset = new carto.source.Dataset(`
   ca_gasdistribution_edited_2
 `);
 const gasDistributionStyle = new carto.style.CartoCSS(`
   #layer {
       marker-width: ramp([gas_released], range(5, 20), quantiles(5));
       marker-fill: #005fec;
       marker-fill-opacity: 0.9;
       marker-allow-overlap: true;
       marker-line-width: 1;
       marker-line-color: #FFFFFF;
       marker-line-opacity: 1;
   }
 `);
 const gasDistributionLayer = new carto.layer.Layer(gasDistributionDataset, gasDistributionStyle, {
   featureClickColumns: ['local_date','significant','serious','operator_id','name','commodity_released_type','gas_released','fatal','injure','ignite_ind','explode_ind','num_pub_evacuated','location_type','incident_area_type','crossing','system_part_involved','installation_year','pipe_diameter','pipe_manufacture_year','material_involved','release_type','class_location_type','total_cost_current','accident_psig','mop_psig','accident_identifier','cause','cause_details']
 });
//GAS TRANSMISSION
 const gasTransmissionDataset = new carto.source.Dataset(`
   gtgg2002_to_present_1
 `);
 const gasTransmissionStyle = new carto.style.CartoCSS(`
   #layer {
       marker-width: ramp([unintentional_release], range(5, 20), quantiles(5));
       marker-fill: #00b300;
       marker-fill-opacity: 0.9;
       marker-allow-overlap: true;
       marker-line-width: 1;
       marker-line-color: #FFFFFF;
       marker-line-opacity: 1;
   }
 `);
 const gasTransmissionLayer = new carto.layer.Layer(gasTransmissionDataset, gasTransmissionStyle, {
   featureClickColumns: ['significant','serious','system_type','operator_id','name','local_datetime','incident_resulted','commodity_released_type','unintentional_release','intentional_release','fatal','injure','ignite_ind','explode_ind','num_pub_evacuated','location_type','incident_area_type','crossing','pipe_facility_type','item_involved','pipe_type','pipe_diameter','pipe_wall_thickness','pipe_smys','pipe_seam_type','pipe_seam_details','pipe_manufacture_year','release_type','class_location_type','could_be_hca','pir_radius','total_cost_current','accident_psig','mop_psig','accident_identifier','cause','cause_details']
 });

//HAZARDOUS LIQUID
 const hazardousLiqDataset = new carto.source.Dataset(`
   hl2002topresent
 `);
 const hazardousLiqStyle = new carto.style.CartoCSS(`
   #layer {
       marker-width: ramp([unintentional_release_bbls], range(5, 20), quantiles(5));
       marker-fill: #EE4D5A;
       marker-fill-opacity: 0.9;
       marker-allow-overlap: true;
       marker-line-width: 1;
       marker-line-color: #FFFFFF;
       marker-line-opacity: 1;
   }
 `);
 const hazardousLiqLayer = new carto.layer.Layer(hazardousLiqDataset, hazardousLiqStyle, {
   featureClickColumns: ['serious','ipe','operator_id','name','local_datetime','commodity_released_type','commodity_subtype','unintentional_release_bbls','intentional_release_bbls','recovered_bbls','net_loss_bbls','fatal','injure','ignite_ind','explode_ind','num_pub_evacuated','significant','incident_area_type','crossing','pipe_facility_type','item_involved','pipe_diameter','pipe_wall_thickness','pipe_manufacture_year','installation_year','release_type','water_contam_ind','could_be_hca','commodity_reached_hca','total_cost_current','accident_psig','mop_psig','accident_identifier','cause','cause_details','location_type']
   });
//US PIPELINES
 const usPipelinesDataset = new carto.source.Dataset(`
   us_pipelines
 `);
 const usPipelinesStyle = new carto.style.CartoCSS(`
   #layer {
     line-width: 3;
     line-color: #4CC8A3;
     line-opacity: 1;
   }
   #layer {
    [pipeline_type = 'Petroleum Product']{
      line-color: #2a36c6;
    }
    [pipeline_type = 'Hydrocarbon Gas Liquid']{
      line-color: #15ad19;
    }
    [pipeline_type = 'Crude Oil']{
      line-color: #c40808;
    }
   }
 `);
 const usPipelines = new carto.layer.Layer(usPipelinesDataset, usPipelinesStyle);

//GAS INTRASTATE AND INTERSTATE PIPELINES
 const gasIntraInterDataset = new carto.source.Dataset(`
   natural_gas_interstate_and_intrastate_pipelines_1
 `);
 const gasIntraInterStyle = new carto.style.CartoCSS(`
   #layer {
     line-width: 3;
     line-color: #31aac2;
     line-opacity: 1;
   }
 `);
 const gasIntraInter = new carto.layer.Layer(gasIntraInterDataset, gasIntraInterStyle);

//CA GAS MIDSTREAM PIPELINES
 const ca_MidStreamGasDataset = new carto.source.Dataset(`
   ca_midstream_gas
 `);
 const ca_MidStreamGasStyle = new carto.style.CartoCSS(`
   #layer {
     line-width: 3;
     line-color: #31aac2;
     line-opacity: 1;
   }
 `);
 const ca_MidstreamGas = new carto.layer.Layer(ca_MidStreamGasDataset, ca_MidStreamGasStyle);
//DEMOGRAPHICS
const demographicsDataset = new carto.source.SQL('SELECT * FROM demographics');
const demographicsDataset = new carto.source.Dataset('demographics');
   const demographicsStyle = new carto.style.CartoCSS(`
   #layer {
     polygon-fill: ramp([perc_bpov], (#efec3a, #efe837, #f0df32, #f2d62d, #f3cc27, #f4c121, #f5b41a, #f8a611, #f99a0b, #fa8f05, #fb8800), quantiles, "=", category);
   polygon-opacity: .3;  
   }
   #layer {
     [zoom < 9] {
         polygon-fill: ramp([perc_bpov], (#f9f8b0, #f9f5af, #f9f2ad, #faefab, #faeba9, #fbe6a6, #fbe1a3, #fcdba0, #fdd79d, #fdd29b, #fdcf99), quantiles, "=", category);
   polygon-opacity: 1;
       }
   }
   #layer::outline {
     line-width: 1;
     line-color: #FFFFFF;
     line-opacity: 0.5;
   }
   image-filters: colorize-alpha(#f9f8b0, #f9f5af, #f9f2ad, #faefab, #faeba9, #fbe6a6, #fbe1a3, #fcdba0, #fdd79d, #fdd29b, #fdcf99);
         `);

   const demographicsLayer = new carto.layer.Layer(demographicsDataset, demographicsStyle, {
     featureClickColumns: ['totalpop', 'hsholds', 'perc_bpov', 'per_cap_inc']
   });



//DRAW LAYERS ON MAP
 client.addLayers([demographicsLayer, ca_MidstreamGas, gasIntraInter, usPipelines, hazardousLiqLayer, gasDistributionLayer, gasTransmissionLayer]);
 client.getLeafletLayer().addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CARTO.js' `.show()` and `.hide()` methods. They will allow you to hide and show independently each layer added to your map. You can find the documentation [here](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/reference/#cartolayerlayer).

You can build your layer selector using that methods. By adding a checkbox to every layer in the legends, you can do something like this:

Checkbox HTML:

`<input type="checkbox" id="nameOfYourLayer" checked/>`

JS Code:

`document.querySelector('#nameOfYourLayer').addEventListener('click', event => 
  event.target.checked ? layerVariable.show() : layerVariable.hide()
);`

You can make it more generic targeting every checkbox and managing the current layer state inside your application.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I have been unable to get this to work. I'm not sure where to put the listener. I've put the input tags into my legend: `<p class="gasDistTitleText">Gas Distribution Incidents <input type="checkbox" id="distribution" checked/></p>` I've tried putting the document querySelector in a variety of places: just under the opening <script> tag,     `document.querySelector('#distribution').addEventListener('click', event => 
  event.target.checked ? distribution.show() : distribution.hide()
); , underneath the client.addLayers` tag, and within the popup code (just to try).

Comment: Got it! I wasn't using the correct layer name. I was thinking the nameOfYourLayer was whatever ID I gave input rather than the actual layer name : }

Comment: Great to read that :)
I am going to explain it clearly to avoid confussions.